# Cant revert accidental SVN detele, neither un-version a local copy

Tags: svn, revert

I did an accidental delete to a subdirectory within a larger project - in my local copy.
Normally, when my local copy gets screwed up, I just revert it. This time it just does not work.
Never mind...
 Other way is to rename parent directory and get a new copy from repository. Then locally merge wanted changes and its a bright day again.
But this time, when I do it, I just can't get rid of accidental SVN delete operation. Its still there, even if I get a new copy from repository to a directory with same name.
I assumed, that I need somehow un-version the local directory, so my TortoiseSVN "knows" that I want to forget that delete. I followed this manual to un-version a local copy:

http://tortoisesvn.net/unversion.html

(even this is much too weird way to un-version a local copy, isn't it ??)
BUT ! Lo and behold, my smile got frozen, to find that after new copy to a new directory of the same name, on the same path, my unwanted delete is still there !!! Can't commit anything any more.

Now, either this is a huge SVN bug, or I am an airplane.

Someone help please ...

```
My TortoiseSVN version:
Windows 7
TortoiseSVN 1.8.7, Build 25475 - 64 Bit , 2014/05/05 20:52:12
Subversion 1.8.9, -release
apr 1.5.1
apr-util 1.5.3
serf 1.3.5
OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
zlib 1.2.8
```

Comment: With this Tortoise version I also observe other very strange, errorneous behavior (when auto merging and others), so I want to ask the community, isn't this version just screwed up ?

Comment: Or could it be incompatible version of server/client ?
I dont know the server version thought, but its at least 2-3 years old, while my Tortoise client is from april 2014

Comment: I've never seen that sort of issue before on any version of SVN. Maybe a "cleanup" command will help, but in general a revert/update should fix things. I'd suggest trying it from the command-line client; then if that doesn't work either contact the SVN mailing list for more help.

Comment: @Ben
Thank you for the answer - I tried cleanup - did not help.
Now I kow the date of SVN server release: Oct 29 2012
Which corresponds to TortoiseSVN 1.7.10, while I have TortoiseSVN 1.8.7

Comment: I solved the issue with update of the TortoiseSVN client to 1.8.8 ...
   And yes, I had 4 troyans imported with Miranda...